# Why did Connie Sumner use tissue paper in the train's restroom after having physical contact with Paul?

Tags: plot-explanation, unfaithful

In [Unfaithful (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0250797/), why did Connie Sumner use the tissue paper in the train's restroom after having physical contact with Paul?

Comment: Ask your mom. There is a whole conversation that should come along with this answer.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, since it seems no one else wants to touch this one, I'll take it.

**She is wiping up the semen.**

After sex, semen doesn't stay inside a woman very well. Especially when she's standing, as gravity pulls it down. To prevent semen from dribbling down her leg and staining her pants (or skirt; I don't remember), she wipes it up, much like she would wipe after urinating.

Answer (score -1):

IMO-I think that due to her fantasizing and recalling her recent sex action with
her lover just before going back home gave her orgasm {strong!} so consequently
she had extreme wetness from it. Had it been semen she would have cleaned up upon
getting aboard the train!